# React functional component has not re-render with same state or props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this case I'm sending same props and state for Child component, so... why has not re-render without `React.memo()` and those logs show just once?

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Child = ({ num }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      {console.log('Child rendered')}
      {count}<br />
      {num}<br />
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count)}>Add</button>
    </>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      {console.log('App rendered')}
      <Child num={num} />
      <button onClick={() => setNum(num)}>Add</button>
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: @Quentin I don't think the the duplicate mark is really correct. There are subtle differences. It's not such a big deal, because I believe the question should be closed regardless as a 'Not reproducible or was caused by a typo', but I find the duplicate a bit misleadiing, especially if I were the OP

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing any values

```js
() => setNum(num)
```

is the same as

```js
() => setNum(0)
```

which is the same as initital state (`0`), hence no re-render occurs

Answer (score 0):

The child component doesn't rerender because the state reference to `num` never changes. It is always set to the same reference. react uses shallow reference equality to reconcile state and prop updates.

```
const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      {console.log('App rendered')}
      <Child num={num} />
      <button onClick={() => setNum(num)}>Add</button> // <-- same object reference
    </>
  )
}
```